# How to read multiple 2d arrays from a .txt file disregarding the newline between each?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble reading multiple 2d arrays from a .txt file. File consists of a number followed by 2d array.  This always results in incomplete 2d array and ill have part of my array read instead of the num(1, 2).
Contents of txt file:

```
1
56758
57749
62416
73684
51425

2
465
45638
3 5 2
1 7
28389
```

What ive got so far:

```
  int main
    {
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("lol.txt",ios::in);
    char myArray[5][5];

    while (inputFile)
    {
    inputFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    int num;
    inputFile>>num;
    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
     {
         for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
         {
             inputFile.get(myArray[row][col]);

         }

     }

    for(int row=0;row<5;row++)
        for(int col=0;col<5;col++)
        {
            cout<<myArray[row][col];

        }
        validator(myArray, num);
```

}
}

Comment: The incomplete lines, are they padded with spaces at the end? Perhaps you should think about checking the character you read before putting it in the array, and think about what should happen if you read a newline.

Comment: Yes. They are padded with spaces at the end.

Comment: You still need to think about those newlines in the file. They will be read as a character like any other.

Comment: Okay I will give it a try. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score -1):

You can declare a string and read each row as string, depends on what you will do with the array.
if its only to output it you can do the follow:

```
string row;
while(row){
   cout<<row<<endl;
}
```

This will output the file as it is
if you're looking to use each element of the row you can use char elt and exchange row by elt and change it to int using stoi

Comment: for each character usage you can get the number of character n in the file and use this method " for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {myfile.seekg(i, ios::beg);
 char c;
 t.get(c);} "